# How discard empty HTML form inputs from $_FILES array

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I have a HTML form with multiple file inputs

```
<input type='file' id='images' name='images[]'>
```

I use implode() to covert the $images array into comma separated string and insert it into my DB , then when calling I use explode() to recall single images.

the problem is : empty input fields are still submitted to the database , so when exploded, I get empty array values

how can I get rid of these empty array values ? maybe even before using implode function ?

I'm thinking of running a foreach loop throw the $_FILES['images'] array and  discarding empty values from it and rebuilding a new array .. but is any easier method available ?

thanks

Comment: write more details about your program. [ your submit form. and code php code that handle these images ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[array_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)**. It is a function which iterates over an array with another function specified as an argument. **But** if you don't pass this argument, the `array_filter` will simply get rid of the values equal fo `FALSE`.

```
$images = implode(',', array_filter($_FILES['images']));
```

Comment: Dont forget that array_filter also removes (int) 0 if you use it without a callback function, so consider using something like an anonymous function to make sure its empty and not (int) 0 (aka == false)

Comment: Just what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

`$images = array_filter($_POST['images']);`

But I would rethink the database design.  You probably shouldn't be storing lists like that.